# Best way to display a custom font in a MS Word document for multiple users

Tags: html, image, fonts, ms-word

We have a document management system which stores hundreds of document templates and precedent letters for our law firm.

What is the best way to have our branding font display in the footer of most documents when the staff PC's and client PC's won't have the branding font installed?
We're trying to determine the best way to have our branding displayed with the least end-user issues.

The document creators have started playing with using the footer text in an image and adding the image to the document, but, for obvious reasons, this poses a performance problem when the size of the document is now 500KB rather than 20KB (for example).  The use of a higher resolution image (to avoid clarity problems) makes the size of the document larger.
They've been working with a 96DPI PNG file.  When they use the MS Word image compression features, the file size is reduced but the image quality becomes degraded.
Is there a better image format they can use?  Or a format with better compression ability?

On a different direction to achieving what they desire, I'm aware you can embed fonts into MS Word documents...  At what point does the embedding of our font need to be done though?  On the server template before the desired document is generated or on the staff PC before the document is sent to clients?   Ideally, we don't want to have to install the font on 250+ computers.

What about HTML/CSS?  I'm quite good with web design and know how to host a font externally and style elements a web page with the font using CSS?  Can something similar be done using MS Word?

Thanks in advance for answers or suggestions to any of the above questions on this topic.

Comment: PDF and EPS can store font information. This lets you display and print these documents without having the original font installed. You could try to embed these filetypes. There is another benefit: The fonts will still be vector shapes and be sharp. Pixel based images are rasterised before output and give jagged edges. That is, if Word does mess up... Your milage may vary. Last but not least: ask you legal department if the font licence allows embedding. ;)

Comment: It's a google web font.  Open Sans... "embedability" is "editable".
It's our secondary branding font, so the fallback is Arial.
I'll look into embedding a vector PDF version of the graphic they've been using.

Comment: Your preferred method ought to be embedding the font in the template(s) (and ensuring Word is configured to "embed fonts in file").  If you don't want to do that, use an image.  It shouldn't affect performance (but will have some impact on storage requirements).